# How do I delete data between specific words with <> brackets?

Tags: notepad++, visual-studio-code

I have this the below data, I wish to delete everything in between `<statMods>` and `</statMods>` I've tried the countless methods mentioned here, but I think the '<>' brackets are conflicting somehow. I am using VS Code and Notepad++.

```xml
 <statMods>
    <Item>
        <identifier />
        <modifier value="25" />
        <audioApply value="1.00000000" />
        <weight value="20" />
        <type>VMT_ENGINE</type>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <identifier />
        <modifier value="50" />
        <audioApply value="1.00000000" />
        <weight value="20" />
        <type>VMT_ENGINE</type>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <identifier />
        <modifier value="75" />
        <audioApply value="1.00000000" />
        <weight value="20" />
        <type>VMT_ENGINE</type>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <identifier />
        <modifier value="100" />
        <audioApply value="1.00000000" />
        <weight value="20" />
        <type>VMT_ENGINE</type>
    </Item>
</statMods>
```

Answer (score 2):

In notepad++, open Replace (ctrl+H), set search mode to regex, enable ". matches newline", and use this search string:

```
<statMods>.*?(</statMods>)
```

Then Find, to make sure it selects the correct text, and Replace with empty

The `?()` non-greedy syntax just makes it select the first `</statMods>` in case you have multiple instances

Comment: Just for info: the capture group is useless and slows down the process.